# NetworkX MultiDiGraph : Adding new attribute to existing node

Tags: python, networkx

so I came across this situation when trying out MultiDiGraph and I would appreciate some guidance:

```
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
setA= ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
G.add_nodes_from(setA,entity='typeA')

setB = ['a','x','y','z']
G.add_nodes_from(setB,entity='typeB')
print([node[0] for node in G.nodes(data='entity') if node[1]=='typeA'])
```

Apparently, this results in overwriting the 'entity' attribute of node 'a' and printing '['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']'

Since I suspect this is intentional
on part of NetworkX, is there any viable workaround for what I am trying to achieve?

Thanks a lot~

Comment: I guess one way would be to do the following:
G.add_nodes_from(setA,typeA=True)
G.add_nodes_from(setB,typeB=True)
print([node[0] for node in G.nodes(data='typeA') if node[1]])
but is there anything prettier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @[Νίκος Γιαλίτσης](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6152672/%CE%9D%CE%AF%CE%BA%CE%BF%CF%82-%CE%93%CE%B9%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%AF%CF%84%CF%83%CE%B7%CF%82). One-Hot Encoding is a general feasible way. Moreover, a [networkx.MlutiDiGraph](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/multidigraph.html) data is a node(or edge tuple) binded with an attributes dict, that is, any python dict format will make sense! e.g.:

```
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
setA = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
G.add_nodes_from(setA, entity={"typeA":True, "typeB":False})

# or
entityA = {"typeA":True, "typeB":False}
G.add_nodes_from(setA, entity=entityA)

attr = {"entity": entityA}  # or simply assign entityA to attr.
G.add_nodes_from(setA, **attr)

G.add_nodes_from(setA, entity=[True, False], entity_label=["typeA", "typeB"])
G.add_nodes_from(setA, entity=list(entityA.values()), entity_label=list(entityA.keys()))
……
```

Then the problem remains how to get the value of each node type. (Set the binary weight for each type, and calculate biwise Xor maybe a good choice.)
PS: Edge attributes can be added in the same way. The pattern of attributes will expand to be an ajacent matrix of entity type graph.